# django response redirect with parameters site suffix becomes null during Delete

Tags: django

I display list of details in id = 3 in this page using this url

http://192.168.1.16:8000/property/info/7/3/

If i click on delete button functionality works good but Error during 
Redirecting to same URL

only this part of url gets display in address bar. /property/info/7/

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('property_info',args=[prop_id,7]))
```

I had used site suffix for url

Comment: What is the error ? Is the destination URL a valid URL ?

Comment: responseredirect site_suffix becomes empty

Comment: Can you please post the complete code of the view function as well as the corresponding entry in urls.py? It's hard to assist you with the information given.